# Reference error: Restify is not defined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run the following node.js script(my first):

```
// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});p

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: MY_ID_VALUE,
    appPassword:MY_PASSWORD_VALUE
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// Receive messages from the user and respond by echoing each message back (prefixed with 'You said:')
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});
```

And i get the error `Reference error :Restify is not defined`, the full error message is attached below.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAZ3Y.png)

So obvious issue i could think of is installing restify again although i already have so i ran this command `npm install --save restify` as i already have following the instruction on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart step by step, how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you import restify module before create the server?

**var restify = require('restify');**